# Is there any fast way to modify this kind of dictionary?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a such dict with following data structure:

```
{'index_1':[('time_1',[ ['a',1],['b',1],['c',1] ]),
            ('time_2',[ ['a',100],['c',100] ]),
            ('time_3',[ ['a',200],['b',200],['c',200] ]),
            ('someting_time', [ ['something_name','something_val'] ... ])
           ],
 'index_2':['something same as above' ]
}
```

This is mostly indexed by the 'time_x'. But I really want to change the dict to the following style:

```
{'index_1':{'a':{'time_1':1,'time_2':100,'time_3':200},
            'b':{'time_1':1,'time_2':'NO_VAL','time_3",200},
             .... 
             ....
}
```

Is there any fast way to do this changing? I can go through each list/dict but I have to consider the performance or a a good data structure because of more same lookup actions.

Thanks

Comment: "I can go through each list/dict".  What's wrong with that?  It's the data structure you already have.  Dictionary lookups use a hash and are **O**(1).  How could you possibly improve on that?

Comment: Thx, the original dict is a 'list' based style dict. will build new dict will cause some performance issue? Basicly i want to calc the average number, for example: (time_1(b)-time_2(b))/(time_1 - time-2),that's why i want to modify the original data structure.

Comment: Why some magical `'NO_VAL'` constant? Why not just leave the key absent? It's trivial to handle a missing key in the code that will use the data later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any faster ways to re-organize a dict than going through everything using loops. I've found that if you have really complicated dictionary entries, you probably should be using a class.

Here's a quick code snippet to do what you asked. It doesn't do the 'NO_VAL', but if the time_x isn't in there you could do a try except KeyError pretty easily.

#

```
a={'index_1':[('time_1',[ ['a',1],['b',1],['c',1] ]),('time_2',[ ['a',100],['c',100] ]),('time_3',[ ['a',200],['b',200],['c',200] ])],'index_2':[('time_1',[ ['a',1],['d',1],['c',1] ]),('time_2',[ ['a',100],['c',100] ]),('time_3',[ ['a',200],['b',200],['c',200] ])]}

d={}

for key in a.keys():
    d[key]={}
    for time in a[key]:
        for name in time[1]:
            if name[0] in d[key]:
        d[key][name[0]][time[0]]=name[1]
            else:
                d[key][name[0]]={time[0]:name[1]}


print d
```

#

Comment: yes, i'm thinking about the change the original dict, actually it is generated with re block matching.